# Using Structures and Arrays in VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net, structure, variable-assignment

My IS Assignment requires me to open a text file containing client information using vb.net. The actual assignment is really lengthy, but iam stuck in this part here.

here is the link to the question.Please note that I do not need the assignment solution as I want to do it on my own, but iam stuck in the first part

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/amw9b6i0o47inau/AAD9uZh4zuBp5MkAEKjiTRX9a?dl=0

Comment: Check out System.IO.File.ReadAllText() or System.IO.File.ReadAllLines() to get your started.

Comment: Page 4 tells you how to process the file data. Pretty detailed.

Comment: ummm I havent really done anything on this!, looks like storing the information from the text into the arrays is the first step.. and I am not even sure how to do that bit!

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8w49z6dy7b8amsk/Query.rar?dl=0
@Sam 
Heres what I;ve done so far, I ve tried opening the file, reading the lines, and trying to store it in the structure variable. I keep getting some errors. The code is in the .rar files, I used SharpDevelop 4.4.